# How to get the element position when sorting a CloudKit field?

Tags: swift, sorting, cloudkit

I am making a ranking of user points, and I want to display the top 9 users + the current user, showing his position relative to the others. Right now, I have two separate queries:

1. Queries only the current user score.
2. Queries the top 9 scores (excluding the current user) by using SortDescriptors.

Is there a method to modify my 1st query in order to get the relative position of that score on the sorting list?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer...

```
let predicate1 = NSPredicate("self.label = 'foo'"))
let predicate2 = NSPredicate("self.label = 'bar'"))
let compound = NSCompoundPredicate.andPredicateWithSubpredicates([predicate1, predicate2])
```

You make your second query a sub of the first... so this says get all the records with "foo" in them and then further cut down my list by returning only those with "bar" too.